# Blowfish algorithm in iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am new in iphone and want to know that which encryption technique is used in iphone to secure our application content. Which encryption is used between ipohne and a asp.net website.
Actually i want to encrypt my message in my applcation which sends to a websites which runs on asp.net. And when websites sends message from .net it will decrypt message in my application.

2nd question can i use blowfish algorithm in iphone application. Because webpage of asp.net is use blowfish algorithm.
How to  implement blowfish algorithm in iphone for ancryption.

Answer (score 0):

For encryption between device and website, SSL (i.e. HTTPS) is the simplest, best supported, most straightforward method, and is supported "out of the box" by `NSURLConnection` etc.

Schneier provides a [C implementation of Blowfish](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html) which can easily be incorporated into your app (Objective-C is a strict superset of C).

Comment: Can you help me how to use C implementation of Blowfish in xcode.

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I am trying blowfish algorithm but it is giving so mush error. I have imported openssl api.and using openssl/blowfish.h filr.

Comment: Schneier's implementation is extremely basic, the only external function calls it makes are to `fopen`, `fread` and `fclose`. Substituting these for their iOS counterparts (or even just inlining the data) is sufficient to make it work.

Comment: As you suggested, i used Schneier code in c. But i have trouble to divide plain text as a left half  and right half to pass into encrypt function.